# cordova-plugin-whitelist not working when using Phonegap build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm having an issue where the whitelist plugin won't work for Android, which causes every AJAX call to return a 404, this breaks my app since I can't connect to my backend server. iOS works fine because it doesn't require this plugin, if I check the plugins list in http://build.phonegap.com it does appear, what could be happening here?

Here's my config.xml (this project uses XDK by the way, so my config.xml is built by it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android-versionCode="7" ios-CFBundleVersion="7" version="1.0.7" id="com.project.app"  >
<!-- This file was generated by the Intel XDK Cordova Package Build tool. -->
<name>PROJECT NAME</name>
<description>PROJECT DESCRIPTION</description>
<author>COMPANY</author>
<content src="index.html"/>
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
<platform name="android" >
    <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://app.project.com/"/>
    <allow-intent href="maps:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://maps.google.com/"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <access origin="http://app.project.com/"/>
    <access origin="tel:*"/>
</platform>
<platform name="ios" >
    <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://app.project.com/"/>
    <allow-intent href="https://www.google.com/maps"/>
    <allow-intent href="https://*.google.*"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <access origin="http://app.project.com/"/>
    <access origin="tel:*"/>
</platform>
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />
<preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="false" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.6"/>
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="2.2.1"/>
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.4.3"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="1.7.1"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="4.0.3"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.3"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist"/> <!-- If available via Cordova registry; consider changing to an NPM reference. -->
<platform name="android" >
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23"/>
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
    <preference name="android-signed" value="true"/>
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop"/>
</platform>
<platform name="ios" >
    <preference name="deployment-target" value="9.0"/>
    <preference name="ios-configuration" value="production"/>
</platform>
<splash platform="android" src="package-assets/splashs/ANDROID/320x426.png" density="ldpi" width="320" height="426" orientation="portrait"/>
<splash platform="android" src="package-assets/splashs/ANDROID/320x470.png" density="mdpi" width="320" height="470" orientation="portrait"/>
<splash platform="android" src="package-assets/splashs/ANDROID/480x640.png" density="hdpi" width="480" height="640" orientation="portrait"/>
<splash platform="android" src="package-assets/splashs/ANDROID/720x960.png" density="xhdpi" width="720" height="960" orientation="portrait"/>
<splash platform="ios" src="package-assets/splashs/ios/640x960.png" width="640" height="960" orientation="portrait"/>
<splash platform="ios" src="package-assets/splashs/ios/640x1136.png" width="640" height="1136" orientation="portrait"/>
<splash platform="ios" src="package-assets/splashs/ios/750x1334.png" width="750" height="1334" orientation="portrait"/>
<splash platform="ios" src="package-assets/splashs/ios/768x1024.png" width="768" height="1024" orientation="portrait"/>
<splash platform="ios" src="package-assets/splashs/ios/1242x2208.png" width="1242" height="2208" orientation="portrait"/>
<splash platform="ios" src="package-assets/splashs/ios/1536x2048.png" width="1536" height="2048" orientation="portrait"/>
<splash platform="ios" src="package-assets/splashs/ios/2048x2732.png" width="2048" height="2732" orientation="portrait"/>
<icon platform="android" src="package-assets/iconos/android/project48.png" density="mdpi" width="48" height="48"/>
<icon platform="android" src="package-assets/iconos/android/project72.png" density="hdpi" width="72" height="72"/>
<icon platform="android" src="package-assets/iconos/android/project96.png" density="xhdpi" width="96" height="96"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project29.png" width="29" height="29"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project58.png" width="58" height="58"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project87.png" width="87" height="87"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project120.png" width="120" height="120"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project180.png" width="180" height="180"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project152.png" width="152" height="152"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project80.png" width="40" height="40"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project57.png" width="57" height="57"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project114.png" width="114" height="114"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project144.png" width="144" height="144"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project100.png" width="100" height="100"/>
<icon platform="ios" src="package-assets/iconos/ios/project187.png" width="187" height="187"/>
<config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest/application" mode="merge">
    <activity android:launchMode="singleTop" />
</config-file>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest starting with everything wide open -- remove all of your `allow-intent` and `access` declarations, and have only this:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

And don't have it inside any `<platform />` tags. Move backwards from there, restricting it down to only the domains you want.

Additionally I don't see any mention of your [Content Security Policy](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#content-security-policy). You should set that as well in your html file, as per the documentation. Again, start with it wide open, which I think looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' *" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In your config.xml You must add:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
```

or

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe put this code inside the config.xml

```
<access origin="https://*"/>
<access origin="http://*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://*"/>
```

Comment: Can you write some explanation that make OP can understand answer?

Comment: Should I add this in the allows of Android specifically? or should it be "general" (as in the highest level of tags)?

Comment: <platform name="android" > ponelo aca dentro   </platform> en vez de lo que está actualmente

Comment: I had already tried that, but I did it again to be sure and it didn't seem to work, I still get 404 from every call. I kinda feel like the plugin itself it's not being installed properly when the APK is built, but I cannot seem to find the reason why